# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure - prove some properties

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Let V be vector space in Rˆn.

Using Gram-Schmidt's orthogonalization procedure notations, show that:

a) if j >= 2, v_j is perpendicular to v_i for every i < j and v_j != 0.

b) the set C = { v_1, ... , v_n) is linearly independent

Conclude that C is an orthogonal basis of V.

---

My doubts are:

The exercise does not ask to prove the general procedure itself, right? It only asks to show a sort of particular case, when j >= 2. I've seen proofs using induction. Is this the right approach to the problem?

Once I show a), does it not automatically implies b) and the conclusion asked?

Comment: (a) is asking you "when building the vectors $v_1, \dots , v_n$, show that each vector is perpendicular to all of the previous ones you built".  Then if you think that (a) implies (b) automatically (say "by definition"), then you should write down exactly what it is, because for people like me it is not automatically clear.  Finally, the conclusion follows simply since $n$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space form a basis, and indeed we constructed them to be orthogonal

Comment: regarding (a), I should assume I'm using Gram-Schmidt's procedure when building the vectors v1, ... vn?

Comment: Yes exactly. So i think the common notation is given $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$, you build the vectors $v_1 = u_1$, $v_2 = u_2 - proj_{v_1}(u_2)$, etc

Comment: Hi @NazimJ. Do you think for part a) is enough to show that SUM(start as i = 1; end = j-1) of < v_i, v_j+1> = 0 ?